# Include repository within repository github

Tags: java, git, github, jedis

I have recently been experimenting with Redis and was planning on including it in a Java project of mine and was wondering if there is a way of "including" someone else's repo within yours so I could "include" jedis within my project without it being a dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)

With using it you can include other repositories and always get the latest code from them by updating the submodule.